# Exposed term search from text fields

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views

Hi every one I have exposed taxonomy terms dropdown. I need to search term name from the other text field if any term is selected from the dropdown.

Comment: Do you mean that you have 2 select fields, the second depending on what user selected on the first?

Comment: one field is select fields(terms) and other one is text field. If someone select term a it will search from text field instead of select field.